# What loss function should be optimized so that the model error does not go above a certain MAPE threshold?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, loss-functions

For the resulting regression model it is critically important not to go above the 10% threshold of MAPE (MAPE = abs((pred - fact)/fact). At the same time it is important to minimize the median of errors for the test period. I think RMSLE should come up. But it cannot guarantee that MAPE will not go above the 10 percent threshold. Should I develop my loss function? Is it even possible to come up with this kind of loss function?

Comment: What is your preferred programming language or statistical software package?

Comment: Python (scikit-learn, catboost, LGBM, xgboost). My data is tabular and have only 5000 rows, so neural network I think is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not convinced that such predictions have to exist. For instance, in the simulation below, I cannot achieve such performance for any of the coefficient combinations I tried, and I do not even get close (my best exceeds $87\%$). This leaves me pessimistic that such performance must be possible on my simulated data as well as on your real data.

```
library(MLmetrics)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N)
Ey <- 25 + 2*x
e <- rt(N, 1)
y <- Ey + e
beta0s <- seq(-50, 50, 0.1)
beta1s <- seq(-5, 5, 0.1)

# Loop over possible regression coefficients
#
max_mape <- matrix(NA, length(beta0s), length(beta1s))
for (i in 1:length(beta0s)){
  
  if (i %% 25 == 0){
    print(paste(
      i/length(beta0s)*100,
      "% complete",
      sep = ""
    ))
  }
  
  for (j in 1:length(beta1s)){
    
    # Make predictions
    #
    pred <- beta0s[i] + beta1s[j]*x
    
    # Loop over the predictions
    #
    each_mape <- rep(NA, N)
    for (k in 1:N){
      each_mape[k] <- MLmetrics::MAPE(pred[k], y[k])
    }
    
    # Store the maximum MAPE for this combination of coefficients
    #
    max_mape[i, j] <- max(each_mape)
  }
}

# Display the smallest MAPE across all coefficient combinations
#
min(max_mape) # I get 0.8733133, well above the requirement to be below 0.10
```

However, if you want to hunt for such a solution, if it exists, the math behind it is what you probably would expect. In an unconstrained regression, you seek out the parameter vector $\hat\beta$ giving $\hat y = X\hat\beta$ that minimizes the absolute loss.

$$
\hat\beta = \underset{\beta\in\mathbb R^{p+1}}{\arg\max}\left\{
\overset{N}{\underset{i = 1}{\sum}}\left\vert
y_i - \beta^TX_i
\right\vert
\right\}
$$

(Technically, the $=$ should be $\in$, since the $\arg\min$ need not be unique, but that muddies the notation for little gain.)

You, however, have restrictions on the parameter vector beyond just being a vector of $p+1$ coefficients corresponding to the intercept and the coefficients on the features, however. Thus, compute the constrained optimizer.

$$
\hat\beta = \underset{\beta\in A}{\arg\max}\left\{
\overset{N}{\underset{i = 1}{\sum}}\left\vert
y_i - \beta^TX_i
\right\vert
\right\}\\
A = \left\{
\beta\in\mathbb R^{p+1}\mid 0.1 \le\underset{i}{\max}\left\{\left\vert
\dfrac{
y_i - \beta^TX_i
}{
y_i
}
\right\vert\right\}
\right\}
$$

If $A$ is the empty set, as I suspect is the case in my simulation, then you cannot achieve the required condition that MAPE (really just the APE, since it applies to each observation-prediction pair instead of to the set of predictions) be less than $10\%$. If $A$, however, is not the empty set, then you have a space over which you can look for solutions that minimize the MAE.

As far as software goes, you might be on your own to write specialized optimization software to perform this. However, that second $\hat\beta$ equation is what you want to solve with that software.